# How to delete a line in text file after delete it in datagridview?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am beginner and try to improve my conding skills. I have an issue which I cant fixed.

I have a datagrindview with some values from a text file. I have a delete button and I want to delete some values from datagrindview and also from text file.

To be more specific, I want to delete a random line (for example the line 3) from the table and also I want to delete it from text file, but I can't do the second part (to delete it from text file).

I try some solutions from what I found on stackoverflow, but does not work for me.

I am really a beginner so any help would be appreciated.

```cs
public void deleteBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        int Countup = 0;
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            Countup++;
            if (Countup >= dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count)
            {
                using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                sr.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
        sw.Write(sb.ToString());
    }

    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
    }
}
```

Comment: A text file is  no database where you can delete a random row. Basically you have to overwrite the file with its new content.

Comment: @KlausGütter as you see in the attached image, I tried to overwrite but I had an issue: when I select a row to delete it in the table, in text file will "delete" another row. So how could I do to delete the same line in table and text file cause I tried something and it overwrite the file without first line and I cannot figure out why. That's my really issue.

Comment: Please add your code as text into the question. Not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand the logic related to the selected rows. You have row before and after the selected rows that must be kept.

```cs
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0) {
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    IEnumerator<string> lineEnumerator = File.ReadLines(path).GetEnumerator();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
        if (!lineEnumerator.MoveNext()) {
            break; // If we reached the end of the file.
        }
        if (!row.Selected) { // If row is not to be deleted
            sb.AppendLine(lineEnumerator.Current);
        }
    }
    File.WriteAllText(path, sb.ToString());

    // Delete the selected rows in the gridView
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows) {
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
    }
}
```